# Parsing nested xml file return null data in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am parsing a nested xml file using hivexml serde but it returns null while we select the data from hive table.
Sample xml file is [xml data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si0cz.png).
Query which i created for parsing the xml.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc ( mail string, Type string, Id bigint, Date string, LId bigint, value string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.OptOutEmail"="/Re/mail/text()",
"column.xpath.OptOutType"="/Re/Type/text()",
"column.xpath.SurveyId"="/Re/Id/text()",
"column.xpath.RequestedDate"="/Re/Date/text()",
"column.xpath.EmailListId"="/Re/Lists/LId/text()",
"column.xpath.Description"="/Re/Lists/value/text()")
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/abc/xyz'
TBLPROPERTIES ("xmlinput.start"="<Out>","xmlinput.end"= "</Out>");
```

Please can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the below query. I have loaded the data into the table from a local path.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xmlList ( mail string, Type string, Id 
 bigint, Dated  string, LId bigint, value string)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "column.xpath.mail"="/Re/mail/text()",
 "column.xpath.Type"="/Re/Type/text()",
 "column.xpath.Id"="/Re/Id/text()",
 "column.xpath.Dated"="/Re/Dated/text()",
 "column.xpath.LId"="/Re/Lists/List/LId/text()",
 "column.xpath.value"="/Re/Lists/List/value/text()")
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
 OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
 TBLPROPERTIES ("xmlinput.start"="<Re>","xmlinput.end"= "</Re>");
```

[image]